# Edge coloring, with a special condition

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

I have a problem I am working on that can be reduced to the following case of edge coloring with a special condition.

Let $G$ be a directed graph with infinite vertices that are colored with $m$ colors $\{1,2,...,m\}$, now I want to color edges (with respect to coloring of vertices) in a way that all input edges of every vertex don't have a same color (i.e. For each vertex there exist at least two input edges with different colors). Colors of edges can be different from colors of vertices. Assume that each vertex has more than $2$ inputs.

In other words, I am looking for a spanning subgraph of the initial graph that has two inputs of different colors and at most one output.
How can we do this edge coloring? Are there some conditions to guarantee what we want?

Has anyone seen this problem before? Are there any results? Would you recommend any references or perhaps additional directions to search.

Comment: What if there is a vertex with only one input edge?

Comment: Assume that each vertex has more than 2 inputs.@Bullet51 
Thanks

Comment: What's the role the vertex coloring playing? Must the colors of edges be different from the colors of vertices?

Comment: Am I missing something? The colors of the vertices have nothing to do with the colors of the edges right? And there are also no conditions on the outputs? Then it seems that there is absolutely nothing stopping you from just taking up a pen and do it. E.g. first color all edges black and then for each vertex randomly select exactly one input and color it white.

Comment: We should present a coloring for edges that is dependent to the coloring of vertices.@Bullet51

Comment: So what does "dependent" mean? Following @Vincent 's comment, we can color the input edge from the vertex with the "largest" color.

Comment: I am looking for a spanning subgraph of the initial graph that has two inputs of different colors and at most one output @Vincent

Comment: It is obvious that what you want (two inputs and at least one output, ignore the colors for now) is impossible in finite graphs. So the question if there are conditions on your graph that guarantee that you can find a spanning subgraph of the initial graph that has two inputs and at most one output is already interesting in its own right, with no colors mentioned. On the other hand, once you have such a graph it is clear that you can color the two inputs in each vertex differently because there are no other conditions to reckon with.

Comment: @Vincent  At most one output not at least. And also I think like you that without coloring it is an interesting question. But about your last sentence, Do you think that coloring is not really important here and what that you said everything is just finding subgraph?!

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. I did indeed mean at MOST one output, that is the reason that it is impossible in the finite case.

Comment: As for unimportance of coloring: yes, although you might need axiom of choice when the set of vertices is uncountable. But let's say you have a total order on the set of vertices. Then for each vertex $v$ we look at the two inputs. One is coming from the smallest of the two vertices that have an edge into $v$ and the other one is coming from the largest vertex that has an edge into $v$. The one coming from the small vertex we color red and the one coming from the big vertex we color blue.That's all. How to easily get an ordering on the vertex set depends on the background of the problem.

Comment: ...but the fact that the vertex set is a set should be enough, you don't need to use the graph structure, unless it makes life easier.

Comment: @Vincent That's all right. Yes, All of the graphs that I work are infinite.

Comment: Dear @mahdimeisami: would you mind eliminating the *vertex*-coloring from the problem-statement? (As Bullet51 already pointed out, the vertices being colored seems irrelevant to you problem. I presume this was mentioned because in your work the vertices, for extraneous reasons, just happened to be colored by $\{1,\dotsc,m\}$, but here, especially for people reading this in the future, mentioning the coloring of the vertices adds preventable confusion to the thread. I can also do the simplifying of the question, if you like.